# cross compiling using ELDK-5.3, openssl in eldk 5.3, openssl/crypto.h not found

Tags: linux, makefile, openssl, cross-compiling

> While executing make it shows openssl/crypto.h not found, does
>   eldk-5.3 have openssl support. I found only gnutls in it.
>
> How to enable/install openssl support in ELDK-5.3
>
> Meanwhile it was there in eldk4.2.
>
> Please advise on it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crypto.h is the part of openssl-devel RPM. So instead of copy header file manually you can install this RPM to eldk toolchain. It will fix all the dependency crypto.h header file as well.

Answer (score 1):

> I just copied it from eldk4.2 and wow it worked!
>
> Still curious to know about eldk-5.3.

```
cp -Rfp /opt/eldk4.2/arm/usr/include/openssl /opt/eldk-5.3/armv5te/sysroots/armv5te-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/
```